# Why does one htaccess redirect work, but not the other even though they are formatted exactly the same?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the following lines in my htaccess file...

```
RewriteRule ^poolpage.php?poolid=9f30d1c77b91aca6318d179ad5df2b7 /poolpage.php?poolid=9f30d1c77b91aca6318d179ad5df2b7a [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^poolpage.php?poolid=c4899d49e0a26b47bb5d3fd85f2c429a /poolpage.php?poolid=c4899d49e0a26b47bb5d3fd85f2c429 [NC,L]
```

NOTE: Only difference in both is the last character of each URL.

The first one redirects fine.  The second one does not.

Any ideas how this might happen?

Comment: what does the access_log says?

Comment: didn't know that existed.  Googled it and downloaded raw access log and installed 7zip to be able to view it.  it's a large file but I searched for specific ID (i.e. 9f30d1c77b91aca6318d179ad5df2b7a) and it was didn't find it anywhere, so I assume that means there is nothing in the access log related to this redirect.

Comment: It should show something when you access the link, it can be just a simple "200 OK" response (the server giving out the link as is) or a redirect showing wich file was served instead. maybe the access_log has some kind of delay if you're in a shared hosting. try to find the raw access_log file.

Comment: you want to add a in first redirection and remove it from the second one ? or add a to both of them?

Comment: yes, the link with the a used to be the original, true URL, but for reasons I won't get into, the page now shows at the shorter one (without the a). So if anyone tries to go to the original URL (with the a), I want to redirect them to the new, shorter one.

Comment: its giving a 200 OK response

Comment: In flags [NC,L], L stand for last rule I think it just stop execution after first L try remove L from first rule and keep it in last one

Comment: What is the URL being requested in both cases? The point is that neither of those directives would work, if the request contained a query string (this simply cannot be matched by the `RewriteRule` _pattern_). If one of these appears to be working then you are either seeing a cached response, the requested URL is not what we think it is, or "something else" is triggering the rewrite. (However, shouldn't this be an external redirect, not a rewrite?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't test query string in `RewriteRule`. Use instead:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)poolid=9f30d1c77b91aca6318d179ad5df2b7(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^poolpage\.php$ /poolpage.php?poolid=9f30d1c77b91aca6318d179ad5df2b7a [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)poolid=c4899d49e0a26b47bb5d3fd85f2c429a(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^poolpage\.php$ /poolpage.php?poolid=c4899d49e0a26b47bb5d3fd85f2c429 [NC,L]
```